# DAO in Scala with type classes

Tags: scala, dao, implicit

Let my application contains business classes `Order`, `Product`, `Customer`, etc. and I would like to store/retrieve them in/from the database.

Usually, we use the `DAO` pattern for this purpose. That is, we define a `DAO` interface and implementation for every business class: `OrderDAO`, `ProductDAO`, etc. Now I would like to use the *type class* pattern:

```
trait DAO[T] {
  def create(t:T)
  ... // other CRUD operations
}
...
// DAO implementations for specific business objects
implicit object OrderDAO extends DAO[Order] {
   def create(o:Order) {...}
   ... // other CRUD operations
}
...
// create a business object in the database
def create[T](t:T)(implicit dao:DAO[T]) {dao.create(t)}
```

Now my problem is that all `DAOs` use a `DataSource` instance (a factory of database connections) and so I cannot define `DAOs` as `objects`. I should create a singleton instance of the `DataSource` and pass it to all `DAOs` upon their initialisation.

Let's say we have a function to create a `DataSource`:

```
def dataSource():DataSource = {...}
```

How would you implement the `DAOs` with *type classes* ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think type class is the way to go here. Type classes are for describing capabilities, not as a replacement for DI.

For example, if your DAO writes to a key-value store, it may require the capability to convert a class to a Map of keys and values.

In such a case the type class is:

```
trait KeyValuable[T] {
  def toMap(t: T): Map[String, String]
}
```

And it is obvious you can supply each business class with the right implementation regardless of environment. It is an inherit capability of the type, not tied to how you then use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an object that holds all your DAOs and initializes them with your DataSource? Extra indirection but this would work.

I don't know (yet) the best practice to deal with Dependency Injection in Scala but this may work for you as well: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Dependency_Injection

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Sasha. Lift way should work:

```
trait DataSource

class MyDataSource extends DataSource

object DataSources {
  @volatile var dataSource: () => DataSource = () => new MyDataSource
}
```

With such approach you can use `object` without loosing testability.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please explain it ?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in code. It must be var, not def, I edited it.

Comment: With such an approach you actually define in DataSources variable, which holds function - factory of data sources. In production code you may use default value of the variable which is defined in the object DataSources. But in tests you can redefine the variable to return whatever you want.